# Degree of the polynomial $f= A_1+ A_2(x-x_1) +\cdots + A_{n+1} (x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_n)$.

Tags: polynomials

In my book is written that the polynomial $f= A_1+ A_2(x-x_1) +\cdots + A_{n+1} (x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_n)$ has degree no more than $n-1$ can you explain me why? Isn't degree of this polynomial $n$? I am doing Newton's method for polynomials (given $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ and their respective values $f(x_1),f(x_2),\ldots,f(x_n)$).

Comment: Without having more context it's impossible to say much more here; this polynomial clearly has degree $n$.

Comment: You should not exclude "equals" signs and "plus" signs from within MathJax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you show is degree $n.$

BUT if you have values $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n$
Then Newton's method gives a polynomial of the form $a_1+ a_2x+ a_3x^2+\cdots+ a_nx^{n-1}$.  You have $n$ "data points" so put those into this equation to get $n$ equations to solve for the $n$ coefficients so have a polynomial of degree $n-1.$

Comment: Please see my edits for proper MathJax usage. (I'm surprised that someone with a reputation over 16000 didn't do better than what I found here.)